# Including 5.8.13 version of Javers causes weird `9730` error message at build time

Tags: kotlin, gradle, javers

I'm encountering strange behavior when trying to include latest version of Javers (`5.8.13` atm)

adding

```
implementation("org.javers:javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo:5.8.13")
```

into my gradle.build.kts file and then launching a build with

```
gradlew build
```

produces this error message

> Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
>   9730

If I downgrade to the previous version (`5.8.12`), then build completes sucessfully.

Running the build with `--stacktrace` produces this (excerpt of the stacktrace):

```
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9730
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2470)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1257)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1105)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextTag(MXParser.java:1090)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parsePlugin(MavenXpp3Reader.java:2892)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parsePluginManagement(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3186)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parseBuild(MavenXpp3Reader.java:1157)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parseModel(MavenXpp3Reader.java:2456)
2020-04-17T10:50:37.154+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.apache.mav
```

PS : the issue happens for other Javers dependencies of the same version (javers-core, ...) too

Comment: looks like gradle or Kotlin issue

Comment: Had the same issue in Maven. I used Version 5.8.12. wich solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue with Javers v5.9.0 when building on Maven v3.3.3 . Upgrading Maven to v3.6.0 did solve the issue for regular compilation. But it stills fails for Sonar Analysis (using sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398) ...

Answer (score 0):

Updating Javers to **v5.9.1** or later should resolve the issue (see [v5.9.1 release notes](https://javers.org/release-notes))